# how use total colunme in footer jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

iam create jqgrid dynmamic but i have problem. when create footer jqgrid
i want total colunme id with summaryType .but show result  empty
 this demo [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/amir3164/dnfk8hmr/136/)

this my code

```
 $grid.jqGrid({
        data: data,
        colModel: [
            { name: "act", template: "actions" },
            { name: "id", width: 50,
               summaryTpl: "Sum: {0}",
                summaryType: "sum",


            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the problem can be easy explained. The properties `summaryTpl: "Sum: {0}", summaryType: "sum"` are used during **grouping of data** and not for placing some data in the footer row. To fill the footer you can either use `userDataOnFooter: true` option *and* to specify `userData` option too or to call `footerData` to set the content of the footer explicitly.

The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dnfk8hmr/139/ calculates first the sum

```
var i, sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(data[i].id, 10);
}
```

and then uses the options

```
footerrow: true,
userDataOnFooter: true,
userData: { id: sum }
```

to create the footer and to set the calculated sum in the `id` column of the footer row.

Another demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dnfk8hmr/138/ uses `footerData` and `getCol` methods inside of `loadComplete`

```
footerrow: true, // the footer will be used for Grand Total
loadComplete: function () {
    var $self = $(this);
    $self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", {
        id: parseFloat($self.jqGrid("getCol", "id", false, "sum"))
    });
}
```

It's important to remark that `getCol` used in the demo access the data *only from the current page*. You can see that clear on the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dnfk8hmr/140/, where `rowNum` is changed to 2.